# Flyway migration is failing while upgrading it from 6 to 10.8.1

Tags: migration, flyway

I am trying to migrate flyway from version 6 to version 10.8.1 but it is failing with given error.This is also happening for flyway version 7,8,9 as well. I am getting below error because of which pod is going into crashloopbackoff.

ERROR: Validate failed: Migrations have failed validation Detected applied migration not resolved locally: Load Group Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: Load Matrix Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: Load Relationship Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: Load Tactic Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: Load Version Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: Load Technique Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: v6 Load Group Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: v6 Load Matrix Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: v6 Load Relationship Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: v6 Load Tactic Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: v6 Load Technique Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Detected applied migration not resolved locally: v6 Load Version Table. If you removed this migration intentionally, run repair to mark the migration as deleted. Need more flexibility with validation rules? Learn more: https://rd.gt/3AbJUZE